# How to combine left side fields of file on the basis of right hand side data using awk.

Tags: unix, sed, awk

I want to combine the left hand side data if right hand side data is common. 
Input :

```
DAN|ab
NAB|ab
PAT|ab
DAN|asd
DAN|gg
NAB|re
DAN|rr
PAT|rr
NAB|sd
DAN|we
PAT|ww
```

Output should be:

```
DAN,NAB,PAT|ab
DAN|asd
DAN|gg
NAB|re
DAN,PAT|rr
NAB|sd
DAN|we
PAT|ww
```

If right hand side data of pipe is common then merge the left hand side data. 
Please suggest me any solution.

Comment: I was not able to combine it with field seperator. Now I got it !!! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -F"|" '{a[$2]=a[$2]","$1;next}END{for(i in a)print substr(a[i]"|"i,2)}' your_file
```

Tested:

```
> cat temp
DAN|ab
NAB|ab
PAT|ab
DAN|asd
DAN|gg
NAB|re
DAN|rr
PAT|rr
NAB|sd
DAN|we
PAT|ww
> awk -F"|" '{a[$2]=a[$2]","$1;next}END{for(i in a)print substr(a[i]"|"i,2)}' temp
DAN|gg
DAN|asd
NAB|sd
NAB|re
DAN|we
DAN,PAT|rr
PAT|ww
DAN,NAB,PAT|ab
```

Answer (score 1):

Another one:

```
awk -F\| '{A[$2]=A[$2] (A[$2]?",":x) $1} END{for(i in A)print A[i] FS i}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '
  BEGIN {FS="|"}
  {if (vals[$2]) { vals[$2]=vals[$2]","$1 } else { vals[$2]=$1 } }
  END { for (key in vals) { print vals[key]"|"key } }
'
```